# Trying to write to a PDF file using FPDF and FPDI

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I was given a PDF file with spots that needed to be filled out with values from the database. I'm using FPDF library along with FPDI, and it seems like a lot of trial and error to position your text...I had to play around with the X and Y coordinates to get the text in correct spots. Seems like a cumbersome and inefficient way to do it. Am I missing something here ?

```
 require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');
 require_once('fpdi/fpdi.php');

 // initiate FPDI  
 $pdf = new FPDI();  
 // add a page
 $pdf->AddPage();  
 // set the sourcefile  
 $pdf->setSourceFile('1.pdf');  
 // import page 1  
 $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);  
 // use the imported page and place it at point 10,10 with a width of 200 mm   (This is    the image of the included pdf)
 $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 200);  
 // now write some text above the imported page
 $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);

 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',20);  
 $pdf->SetXY(85, 50);  
 $pdf->Write(0, "Johnny Walker");
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',11);
 $pdf->SetXY(92, 69); 
 $pdf->Write(0, "3"); 
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
 $pdf->SetXY(114, 76); 
 $pdf->Write(0, 'Ventilation Management of the Amyotropic Lateral Scleropsis'); 
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
 $pdf->SetXY(114, 90); 
 $pdf->Write(0, date('m/d/Y'));  
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',7);
 $pdf->SetXY(66, 127); 
 $pdf->Write(0, '1.5');  
 $pdf->Output('1.pdf', 'I');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used `FPDF` in the past once and you're right setting XY positions are quite cumbersome. But there doesn't seem to be another way.

The only thing I would suggest is consider

```
$pdf->SetXY($pdf->GetX() + $x_value, $pdf->GetY() +  $y_value)
```

at places where you aren't sure of the exact position you should place at.

Comment: Yeah its completely absurd. This is such a common problem and I don't know why there is no standardized solution for it. I wonder if writing word files is easier...I don't know. BTW your code moves the coordinates from the current position by X_value in horizontal and y_value in vertical, is that correct ?

Comment: Well, I really liked using FPDF actually. It's quite easy to use, But I guess when you need to deal with PDF files for long, then you need a better way than xy coordination. 
Yeah, that's correct. It's just something to keep in mind as sometimes all you need is to add a few lines after 'last' XY position. This way, you won't need to remember exact coordinate points. Just add a few as you go along.

Comment: Adding values to the current position also gets over the problem where you write text from a variable and you don't know how many lines it's gonna take. By explicit values for XY, you might end up lines printed on top of each other.. something like that :D